# How can I change the window icon in my Eclipse (PDE) application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a product I want to change the window icon, is it possible to happen and how?

I use PDE(plugin development) by developing a product based on Eclipse CDT.

Comment: Are you configuring the product through a `*.product` file?

Comment: Yes, I configuring the product via `*.product` @JohnDoe

Comment: Note an Eclipse RCP and an SWT application (which just uses SWT) are different things with different answers. For a RCP with a product file look at the Launching and Branding tabs for the various images you can specify.

Comment: I use PDE(plugin development) by developing a product based on Eclipse CDT. I have a product plug-in with `.product` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder `graphics` in your plugin and you should add there 6 images with the following sizes:

- 16x16
- 32x32
- 48x48
- 64x64
- 128x128
- 256x256

In your `*.product` you will have to configure the path to each icon:

```
<windowImages 
    i16="graphics/icon_16.png"
    i32="graphics/icon_32.png"
    i48="graphics/icon_48.png"
    i64="graphics/icon_64.png"
    i128="graphics/icon_128.png"
    i256="graphics/icon_256.png"/>
```

You should also configure the `build.properties` file to deliver in your product the `graphics` folder. To achieve that, add this line to the `bin.includes` variable from the `build.properties` file:
`bin.includes=some_existing_line,\
             graphics/`

You can also achieve that through the `*.product` editor provided by the eclipse development tools. Right-click on the `*.product` file and select `Open with->Product Configuration Editor`.
In the bottom of the editor select the `Branding Tab`, then you can `Browse` each image:

[image]